# Concise creation of an object with an attribute in Python

Tags: python, attributes, namedtuple

I want to pass an object with attribute `key` set to `42` to function `f`. This will be done only once, and the object and its type is discarded. Here is my solution:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def f(a): 
  print(a.key)

f(namedtuple('T', ['key'])(42))
```

Is there a less cumbersome way than `namedtuple('T', ['key'])(42)`.